# About the proof of a theorem about Linear Programming in C. L . Liu "Introduction to Combinatorial Mathematics"

Tags: linear-programming

I am reading C. L . Liu "Introduction to Combinatorial Mathematics".

I think his proof of the following theorem is not correct.

Am I right?

p.312 Theorem 12-1

> If a linear programming problem has a feasible solution, it also has a basic feasible solution.

His proof:

> Suppose that $\hat{x_1}, \hat{x_2}, \dots, \hat{x_{r+m}}$ is a feasible solution. If all of $\hat{x_1}, \hat{x_2}, \dots, \hat{x_{r+m}}$ are zero, they constitute a basic feasible solution. (In fact, this is a degenerate case in which the feasible region consists only of this one point.) $\cdots$

For example, I think $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0, 0, 0, 0)$ and $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (1, 0, 2, 1)$ are feasible solutions of the following linear programming problem:
$$
-2 x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 \\
-x_1 + x_2 + x_4 = 0 \\
x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \ge 0
$$

Comment: You are right, that comment in the proof is a mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much, LinAlg.